# Python's importlib and inspect for static class members

Tags: python, python-3.8, python-importlib

In a long-running app I need to dynamically modify static class members based on path to the class' module and the class name.

Ex. I have a class `pack1.mod1.Person` and by definition I know it has a `age` property. So utilizing the `importlib` and `inspect` I try to load the class using the module path and class name and update the `age` property. It all seems fine until I read the the `age` property from my naturally imported `Person` class and find it's not updated.

Here are some more details:

```
.
├── app.py
└── pack1
    ├── __init__.py
    └── mod1.py
```

mod1.py

```
class Person:
    age = 42
```

app.py

```
import inspect
import os
from importlib import util

from pack1.mod1 import Person

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Person.age = 3
    print(Person.age)  # => 3

    spec = util.spec_from_file_location('pack1.mod1', os.path.join('pack1', 'mod1.py'))
    module = util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)

    members = inspect.getmembers(module)

    for x, member in inspect.getmembers(module, lambda i: inspect.isclass(i) and i.__name__ == Person.__name__):
        print('Person:', Person.age)  # => Person: 3
        print('Person from inspect:', member.age)  # => Person from inspect: 42
        Person.age = 11
        member.age = 66
        print('Person:', Person.age)  # => Person: 11
        print('Person from inspect:', member.age)  # => Person from inspect: 66
```

In the `app.py` I would expect `member` and `Person` to be the same thing but as the example shows they aren't.

What am I missing and how to achieve such an update on the static members of a class?

Comment: Can you clarify why you are manually importing the module *by file location* at all? Python has no way of knowing that your manually imported module and the regularly module are the same – and thus creates separate objects for them. This problem would not exist without explicitly importing the module like this.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I thought I need to import it so I can read it with `inspect` as in the example. Now I'm guessing this is wrong and there is a better way to get the right class by name. Can you assist?

Comment: Sorry, I am not really sure what problem you are trying to solve. If the names are well-known, you can literally just run ``Person.age = 66``. Even if the names are dynamically defined, one can ``getattr`` and ``setattr`` them. Your code has a huge setup of manual imports, module inspection, and object identification of which I am not sure which ones you *want* and which ones you just assumed are needed.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi TBH my example is simplified version of the real legacy code and I'm not exactly sure why it's implemented that way. I saw your example and it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has no way of knowing that the regularly imported module and the manually module are "the same": Using `util.spec_from_file_location` up to `spec.loader.exec_module` side-steps Python's module registry and explicitly creates a new instance of the module.
Instead, use the native operations of the interpreter (`import`, ...) or their programmatic equivalents (`importlib.load_module`, ...)

If the module/class are well-known, one can `import` it regularly and directly inspect it.

```py
import pack1.mod1
pack1.mod1.Person.age = 66
```

If module and class are only known by name, one can look them up from the existing modules.

```py
import importlib

module_name, qualname, attribute, value = 'pack1.mod1', 'Person', 'age', 66

obj = importlib.import_module(module_name)  # same as `import {module_name}`
for part in qualname.split('.'):
    obj = getattr(obj, part)                # same as `{obj}.{part}

setattr(obj, attribute, value)              # same as `{obj}.{attribute} = {value}`
```